# Had striding of Vali towards 4 oceans daily occurred before formation of Himalayas?

Tags: ramayana, sandhyavandanam, vali

In Ramayana, Surgiva narrates the strength and speed of Vali as follows:

> समुद्रात् ***पश्चिमात् पूर्वम् दक्षिणाद् अपि च उत्तरम्*** | क्रामति अनुदिते
>   सूर्ये वाली व्यपगत क्लमः || ४-११-४
>
> "Before the dawn of sun Vali unweariedly strides from ***western ocean to
>   eastern, and even from southern to northern*** for offering water
>   oblations to the rising sun.

---

We all know that there was no ocean available in Northern side of India right now, except Himalayas.

However, modern theories say that there existed [Tethys ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethys_Ocean), [before  continental collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himalayas#Geology) or orogeny along the convergent boundary between the Indo-Australian Plate and the Eurasian Plate.

Thus, can we infer that the incident of Vali performing Sandhyavandana in 4 oceans occurred  before formation of Himalayas?

Comment: there r mentions of Himalya/Kailasha in Ramayana..

Answer (score 1):

It should not be possible as, in Ramayan, there are various references to Himalaya like Dronagiri, where Sanjeevni was found, and rivers like Ganga which originates from Himalaya.

The origination of Himalaya after the Indian subcontinent collided with the Asian continent must have taken [millions of years](https://www.geolsoc.org.uk/Plate-Tectonics/Chap3-Plate-Margins/Convergent/Continental-Collision). The age of these people were long, but not that long. It must be that on the northern side Vali used some river instead of ocean. If he managed to stride everyday.

Comment: It is like a comment than an answer please

Comment: I was putting it in the comment at first, then thought if it's logical enough it could be an answer.

Comment: Himalayas formed 40 to 50 million years ago, and hominids appeared 15 million years ago, making your proposition a non-starter @srimannarayanakv. Now you may counter this alleging "western-orientedness" on the part of the scientists that arrived at these figures but I'm pretty sure a good majority of folks outside of this hinduism echo chamber would rather lend credence to science than mythology

Comment: By posting a question I had expressed my doubt.  By posting a comment you had expressed your opinion. Thanks. I am not for argument but open for discussion.@iruvar

Comment: @srimannarayanakv gaaru, it appears that you should not be preceding a @ immediately with a .   Your response never reached my inbox.  Luckily I checked back in and saw your response.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for correcting me @iruvar